# NoViableAltException while using Spring Data query with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am specifying a Spring Data query using `@Query` on a repository method but it is throwing a `NoViableAltException` exception.

This is the repository interface method and annotation I am using:

```
@Query(value="SELECT one.saveLine, two.saveLine FROM (SELECT * FROM SaveOutputTable WHERE saveType = 'R' and seqId = '0' and executionId =:executionIdOne ) one JOIN (SELECT * FROM SaveOutputTable WHERE saveType = 'R' and seqId = '0' and executionId =:executionIdTwo) two ON one.lineId = two.lineId")
public List<ResultCompare> findByParamResult(@Param("executionIdOne") long executionIdOne,@Param("executionIdTwo") long executionIdTwo);
```

This causes the following error:

```
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: (
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromRange(HqlBaseParser.java:1501) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1325) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1045) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:730) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:186) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:279) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
```

Comment: did you tried with another `hibernate-core-5.0.9` version, try this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.5.Final

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error has absolutely nothing to do with Hibernate.

You are using the Spring Data annotation, `@Query` which normally takes a JPQL query string.  What you are specifying is a native query SQL string, so you need to modify the annotation and also provide `nativeQuery=true`.