# spring boot jpa @query where clause based on boolean flag param

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot version 2.4.0.

I need to get the data from table where name is not null but it should conditional based on mandflag, if mandflag=true then only name is not null  should be executed.
Kindly suggest how to add this flag based condition in below query.

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM testtable p WHERE name is not null  ")
public List<PatientEntity> findRecords(@Param("mandflag") boolean mandflag);
```

**Edit**
Requirement- Fetch data from table where name is not null if input flag is true

I need data from table where condition should be executed based on boolean flag

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are asking. Could you be more clear please?

Comment: I want to execute query with condition based on param. Here if input mandflag param is true then I need records which does not have name as empty or null if input mandflag param is false then all records should be returned

Comment: Just write 2 methods to do this and execute the one needed based on the boolean.

Comment: You could simply use `select p from testtable p where ?1=false OR (?1=true and name is not null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM testtable p WHERE CASE WHEN :mandflag= TRUE THEN name is not null ELSE 1=1 END", nativeQuery = true)
public List<PatientEntity> findRecords(@Param("mandflag") boolean mandflag);
```

Comment: Hi  now I am getting error antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: is
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: null 
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: end

Comment: References [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766640/java-spring-unexpected-token/40766756), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145271/noviablealtexception-while-using-spring-data-query-with-hibernate) as to what is that error. Anyway, I edited the asnwer so please check it out.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM testtable p WHERE (case when :mandflag = true then name is noy null else name is null end ))
public List<PatientEntity> findRecords(@Param("mandflag") boolean mandflag);
```

Comment: You even had an existing answer, yet you post an incorrect one

Comment: it's different, look carefully. even the variable name was different.